# how use hibernate grails 3,mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

I have MySQL server and 2 applications: web site (grails3) and android app. The database contains the schedule of matches. The android application sends requests to the web server (not MySQL server). If the schedule has been updated, then you must necessarily display it on the phone. How to use hibernate and grails3 for this?

Comment: At what paragraph of grails documentation did you stuck?

Comment: @AntonHlinisty I need help setting up hibernate. I can not find a good guide. I looked this site http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#gettingStarted I do not understand from the point of view 2.2

Comment: Hibernate works for grails "from the box". See: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#quickStartGuide

Comment: @AntonHlinisty I can not find the place where ip, password, server port, database name is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as I've understood from the conversation in comments you have troubles with some of the points of Hibernate configuration.

Section 4 of the doc gives the answer: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#configuration

*grails-app/conf/application.yml* file is responsible for various settings.

Here is example from my training project: https://github.com/ahlinist/tempvs/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.yml

Pay attention to *dataSource* property, login and pass are configured there. Url (with db name) may be configured separately for each type of environment where the given dataSource is used.

Comment: How can I add mysql connector to the project in intellij? java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2;ClassLoader:TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader

Comment: See build.gradle: https://github.com/ahlinist/tempvs/blob/master/build.gradle. There is a line: runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39'

Comment: Help me please whith this qwestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055167/connect-to-mysql-via-hibernate . This continuation of the current issue

Comment: @SanychGoilo, you didn't accept this answer. Wasn't it helpful?