# Connect to MySQL via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

My db:

```
CREATE TABLE `ggloor`.`teams` (
  `idteam` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idteam`));
```

Settings in applicatin.yml

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 1111

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?useSSL=false
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?autoreconnect=true;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?autoreconnect=true;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Created domain

```
package testgrails12

class Teams {
    Integer idteam
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package testgrails12

class Teams {
    Integer idteam
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'idteam', sqlType: 'INT(11)', insertable: false, updateable: false
    }
}
```

I get an error at the execution stage

> Error 500: Internal Server Error URI /bdconnect/index Class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException Message null
>   Caused by Unknown column 'teams0_.id' in 'field list'

I tried to create hibernate.cfg.xml, Teams.hbm.xml in the conf folder, this did not work.

How to set everything up correctly? Work stopped =(

Error after add mapping

> 2017-03-29 19:30:34.954 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat
>   context. Exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message:
>   Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#4bafa64a' of type
>   [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter]
>   while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4bafa64a': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setWebRequestInterceptors'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via
>   constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
>   Repeated column in mapping for entity: testgrails12.Teams column:
>   idteam (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>   2017-03-29 19:30:35.003 ERROR --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

Comment: I don't know anything about `hibernate`, but in your class definition the field is called `teamid`, in your database screenshot its called `idteam` and your error message names the field `id`. Looks inconsistent to me.

Comment: And for that missing id, why don't you use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation?

Comment: @ventiseis I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to remove `Integer idteam` from your entity and let GORM create the DB schema for you.

If you use some legacy database you can align your entity mapping using the `static mapping = {}` closure as given [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html), your id field probably will look like that:

```
static mapping = {
    ....
    id column: 'idteam', sqlType: 'INT(11)', insertable: false, updateable: false
    ....
}
```

Note: you do not need to define it as a field in your entity. Just use it in mapping.

Comment: @SanychGoilo updated the answer with `insertable: false, updateable: false`

Comment: @AntonHlinsty Error persists

Comment: @SanychGoilo we live in the same city, can try to solve your problem offline and then post the solution here

Comment: @AntonHlinsty I solved the problem. i can insert data, but i can not update and delete data. `def team = Teams.get(4) team.delete()` and `team.name = '123' team.save()` is not work, not give results or an error.